# Pass array from js for loop to highcharts series data

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, highcharts

I've created an array (myData) from a for loop and stored it in a variable, however I'm unable to plot the data via highcharts.

I've added an array (arr) containing numbers (i.e not via the for loop) to test and it works when using this array.

Example in http://jsfiddle.net/o22uk7Lb/

HTML

```
myData<p id="demo"></p>
arr<p id="demo2"></p>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var mp = 300;
var yp = (mp * 12);
var year = new Array(12);
var myData = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= year.length; i++){
    myData +=  (i * yp.toFixed(2)) + ",";
};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myData; 

 var arr = [100,200,300,400,500];
 document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arr; 
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: myData
    },]
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is not populating an array, it's creating a string.

Try this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= year.length; i++){
    myData.push(i * yp.toFixed(2));
};
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o22uk7Lb/1/)